# MySQL get parents with the same id and related child

Tags: mysql

Let say we have an mysql table

```
Id    RelatedId
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     2
5     1
6     2
```

How can I delete all records with RelatedId=0 and then childs on Id=RelatedId in a single MySQL query?

Comment: How are they bound together? I mean relatedid referres to parent id or child id?

Comment: In this case RelatedId referred to Id as child to parent

Answer (score 1):

The alterative to ClaireG's answer is to enforce the relationship with foreign keys set to ON DELETE CASCADE.

Comment: This is the best solution!

Comment: @Nick You should learn about the CASCADE concept while using subquery to delete will not work if you don't know the depth of relation CASCADE will do the trick

Comment: The best solution was to add an additional key that makes possible to select/delete in a single query

Answer (score 0):

You have to check it twice:

```
DELETE FROM [yourTableName] 
WHERE RelatedId = 0
   OR (RelatedId in 
         (select id from [yourTableName] where RelatedId = 0))
```

Find all the records where relatedID is null, and find all other ids that are related to 0 (in your case `[1,2]`)

Comment: Select inside delete query on the same table is not allowed

Comment: mysql say: #1093 - You can't specify target table '[yourTableName]' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 0):

seems that works...

```
DELETE
FROM
    delete_table
WHERE
    delete_table.RelatedId IN (
    select Id from(
        SELECT
            s1.Id
        FROM
            delete_table s1
        WHERE
            s1.RelatedId = 0
    ) as x
)
OR delete_table.RelatedId = 0;
```

Comment: this works! but here are too many selects in a single query. Is there no other more optimal solutions?

Comment: i don't think there will be more optimization possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE TABLENAME 
FROM TABLENAME T1
WHERE TABLENAME.ID = T1.RELTED_ID AND T1.RELTED_ID = 0;
```

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set

Comment: Edited the query. Can you try again?